# openpai k8s cluster deploying rest-server failed

Tags: openpai

failed to deploy rest-server latest on k8s cluster

/usr/src/app/src/config/launcher.js: 144
        throw new Error('cannot connect to framework launcher');
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1

python paictl.py service start -n rest-server

I tried v0.12.0 and latest, both failed with the same error. Anybody in OpenPai team could help?

Answer (score -1):

Please check whether framework launcher has been deployed successfully